# Javascript: Function returns 0 instead of the number that appears odd number of times

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to solve a challenge from [Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) where you have to find the number in an array that appears odd number of times. I modified my answer to return the number that appears odd number of times and is most frequent. But it always results in 0

```js
counts={};

function findOdd(A) {
    for (var i=0; i<A.length; i++){
      if ((typeof counts["a" + toString(A[i])]) !== 'undefined'){
        counts["a" + toString(A[i])]++;
      }
      else{
        counts["a" + toString(A[i])]=1;
      }
    }

    max = 0;
    for (a in counts){
      if (counts[a]>max && counts[a]%2!==0){
        max = counts[a]
      }
    }

    return max;
}

var testArray=[];

for (var i =0; i<100; i++){
    testArray.push(Math.ceil(Math.random()*100))
}

console.log(findOdd(testArray));
```

Comment: `toString()` does not do what you think it does because it's actually `window.toString()` and it takes no arguments

Comment: If you log `counts` to the console, you will see that it is `{
  "a[object Undefined]": 100
}`. The problem is your use of `toString`. That's not how you convert a number to a string.

Comment: The prefixing of your object keys with `"a"` is also totally redundant

Comment: @Phil & JLRishe thanks, but i thought Javascript variable don't start with a number, but the code works anyway

Comment: @YogeshBhatt variables cannot be object properties can

Comment: @Phil oh yeah haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in toString(). It's not a normal, global function but it actually is a shortcut to `window.toString()`.

You don't actually need `toString()` for the cases you are using it, Javascript will automatically convert the value to a string for cases like this:

```
'a' + 5; // equals 'a5'.
```

Comment: isnt `.toString()` actually a prototype method of the base object of javascript and not of the window object? or didnt i understand something right?

Comment: Yes, but `window` is an object and has a `.toString()`. So calling it by itself will call the one on `window`